# If Hogwarts has a book and quill that identify children with magical potential, why was Delphini able to avoid detection?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

According to Pottermore, there is [The Quill of Acceptance and the Book of Admittance](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-quill-of-acceptance-and-the-book-of-admittance), which together identify all children who exhibit signs of magical potential. According to the article

> The Quill's sensitivity, coupled with the Book's implacability, have never yet made a mistake.

If so, why was Delphini not identified? Tampering seems unlikely since the book

> has not been touched by human hands since the four founders placed it there on completion of the castle [Hogwarts].

Wouldn't that have meant her name would appear and she would be sent a letter to Hogwarts, thus everyone would know about her?

Comment: My first instinct would be to say, yes, she was, but just did not go.

Comment: The book knew. The guy who is supposed to read the book was slacking off, missed a name? ;)

Comment: You don't *have* to attend do you?

Comment: @ThruGog - Right

Comment: "*The Dark Side clouds everything*" - Lord Yodamort.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We don't know whether her name showed up in the books as

> Delphini **Riddle** (which would have been monumentally surprising), Delphini **Lestrange** (merely *moderately* surprising) or Delphini **Rowle** (not surprising at all)

Obviously when the name appeared, [Voldemort's placeman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severus_Snape) was in control of the school so he may simply have removed her name (e.g. her true name) from the rolls.

---

Even if her name ***did*** show up in the Book of Admittance, [her adopted mother](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Euphemia_Rowle) could have gotten out of sending her by simply telling the school, when she reached the age of 11, that she was too ill to attend or that she intended to home-school her.

> **SCORPIUS:** *You’ve never been to Hogwarts?*
>
> **DELPHI:** *I was — unwell — as a child — for a few years. Other people got to go — I did not.*
>
> **SCORPIUS:** *You were too — ill? I’m sorry, I didn’t know that.*
>
> **DELPHI:** *I don’t advertise the fact — I prefer not to be seen as a tragic case, you know?*

Regardless of her lack of formal education, she *was* evidently well schooled in the dark arts.

Comment: great catch re: Snape being headmaster at the time. Love that answer

Comment: Except Snape wasn't really Voldemort's, so why would he do that without sabotaging it somehow? And it's hard to believe those clown Carrows had either the access or the brainz to destroy evidence

Comment: @WillRosenberg - Snape was a ***deep cover*** double agent. He'd do exactly what a Death Eater would do, which is to subvert the book.

Comment: No argument here, he'd do as instructed but don't you think he'd also leave a note or memory behind for Harry to discover? In order to sabotage voldy's evil plan b?

Comment: @WillRosenberg - Nah, an illegitimate child for Voldemort is embarrassing, but not really a long-term threat.

Comment: Got it, it was a child born of pure love and not some twisted and insane plot of Voldy :) Bellamort4ever XD

Comment: @WillRosenberg - Shagging one of your followers is hardly a "*plot"*.

Comment: Hm, maybe it was really to protect Bellatrix's honour and the feelings of Nagini, who i am sure, would have felt betrayed by Voldy. How gallant.

Comment: The other answer points out that since she was raised by Euphemia Rowle, it's possible that that became her adopted name. Having the name "Delphini Rowle" appear in the book would have been even less suspicious than either "Delphini Riddle" or "Delphini Lestrange".

Comment: @Thundergforge - Good point.  See edit.

Answer (score 3):

The Quill detects potential students when they **exhibit magical abilities**, not when they are born, meaning that she wouldn't have been detected *at birth*, but more probably several years later.

Assuming that the Quill is magical enough to write up an **useful name for the school to find the student**, then rather than her birth name, the Quill might have recorded her adoptive name (Rowle).

Afterwards, her adoptive mother actually claiming she was ill is perfectly credible, and no one at Hogwarts would've questioned it.

Answer (score 1):

If she was Delphini Riddle people probably wouldn't have noticed the surname. Remember, many people didn't know that Tom Riddle and Lord Voldemort were one in the same person. Also I was thinking, who's to say she was born and raised in the UK. The book of admittance and quill of acceptance surely only pick up magical children born and living in The United Kingdom, not the whole world. So perhaps Delphini was born out of the country? (not a hard feat for Voldemort to get Bellatrix to leave for a little while) and then raised outside of the country until she was past the age where she'd receive a Hogwarts letter?

I do like the theories that she was raised under a different surname though. I think that is quite credible.